# liferay 7 cas not logined

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, liferay-7

I'm newbie to liferay 7,I want to integrate liferay 7 with CAS without ldap.

my liferay's version is DXP, CAS server's version is 4.0.0.

I have installed liferay on localhost:8080,CAS server is on one of my server machine over ssl.

I have successfully integrated CAS. After this I have configured CAS authentication in liferay that is in Configuration->Instance Setting->Authentication under this CAS tab. 
When I try to login im getting following url:

```
    http://localhost:8080/?ticket=ST-23-d3Dvgf5h56Fa3ptUf5wEc-cas01.example.org
```

Although ticket is generating,but I'm not able to access admin panel.

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have followed all the instructions in this manual
    https://web.liferay.com/web/nidhi.singh/blog/-/blogs/liferay-intregation-with-cas-and-ldap 
     and everything works perfectly!